# Clustering of array values

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis

I have a pandas dataframe and want to get clusters based on the column's values such that sum of values in a cluster is less than 0.05. Cluster size can be any real value greater than 2. I can apply basic pandas operations to do the same but it can only be done at a certain cluster size. If cluster size is too large, manually coding all possibilities is not feasible. I want to know is there any ML algo. available that can help me with this?

Comment: Not exactly a ML problem, it seems to fit into the binpacking class of problems, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem for hints

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.